# How to pull from a branch of a teammate in my project? GitHub Desktop

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

There is a main project where all users have a particular branch. One of the users has already advanced some modules and I want to pull these changes to my local repo. What I have done is: Switch to their branch (I have tried both stashing my changes in my old branch and bringing them to the new branch) and then I try to fetch and pull. Nevertheless, I only get this response:

[image]

But there are changes in their branch, it simply seems like GitHub Desktop is not detecting them.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S: I want to use GitHub Desktop, I am not as familiar with Git syntax yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have fetched the remote repository, you should be able to see and switch to the remote branch

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/359239/35166883-3475f09e-fd08-11e7-9a50-f047f531afb1.png]

And then create a branch (`Branch > New Branch`) from there.